# Best UI for adding comment, reporting issue, or adding comment & reporting issue

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, user-centered-design

I've been going back and forth on this one all day.

Requirements for a comments section.

- User can add a comment
- User can report an issue without any comment attached
- User can report an issue AND attach a comment.

What I currently have:

[image: User can type then click button to insert comment]

User can type then click button to insert comment

or the arrow portion can be clicked to reveal these options:

[image: The first, reporting an issue, can be selected and automatically report the issue (no extra click.) The second, comment & report, can be selected and if you still need to type your comment it will wait for you to click it again to insert issue and comment.]

The first, reporting an issue, can be selected and automatically report the issue (no extra click.) The second, comment & report, can be selected and if you still need to type your comment it will wait for you to click it again to insert issue and comment

I just know there is a better, less confusing, way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Why you put those requirements in button group after the message? It will be clear if those options are shown before where the user defines what type of message wants.

Also isn't clear that button group is also a call to action for adding comments.

Heres an example:
[image]